# Azure Load balancer( L4) will support SNI?

Tags: azure, sni, azure-load-balancer, apache-pulsar

Currently i set up the **pulsar** in azure vm using this link

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/deploy-bare-metal/

Now i would like to set up the **SNI** to the pulsar cluster is there any way to do this ?

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-proxy-sni-routing/